# I made a send email script but in c# but it is not outputting right

Tags: c#, html, email, dotnetnuke

I built a script to send email in c# when I write the email body here is what it looks like:

```
line 1
Line 2
```

But when I receive it it looks like:

```
 <p>Line 1</p>
 <p>Line 2 </p>
```

Any help would be appreciated in getting it to have the right output as I am new to this. Here is my code:

View.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Scott.SendEmail.View"
CodeFile="View.ascx.cs" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="Label" Src="~/controls/LabelControl.ascx" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TextEditor" Src="~/controls/TextEditor.ascx"%>

<div class="dnnForm dnnEdit dnnClear" id="dnnEdit">


<fieldset>
 <div class="dnnFormItem">
  <table class="dnnFormItem">
   <tr>
    <td>           
     <dnn:label id="plField" runat="server" text="SendTo" helptext="Enter a value" 
     controlname="txtField" />
     <td>
      <asp:textbox id="txtField" runat="server" maxlength="255" />   
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>
       <dnn:label id="plField2" runat="server" text="Subject" helptext="Enter a value"
        controlname="txtField"/>            
      <td>
       <asp:textbox id="txtField2" runat="server" maxlength="255" />
      </tr>    
      <tr>
      <td>
       <dnn:label id="plField3" runat="server" Text="Message" helptext="Enter a value" 
       controlname="txtField" />
     <td>
      <dnn:TextEditor ID="txtField3" runat="server" width="90%" DefaultMode="Rich" 
      HtmlEncode="true" />   
     </tr>
    </table>      
   </div>     
    <Center>
     <ul class="dnnActions dnnClear">
      <li>         
       <asp:linkbutton style="color: white" id="cmdSave" text="Send Email" 
       runat="server" width="200%" cssclass="dnnPrimaryAction" />
      </li>
      </ul>
     </Center>
   </fieldset>
  </div>
```

View.ascx.cs.resx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <data name="plField.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Send Mail To:</value>
  </data>
  <data name="plField.Help" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Select who you would like to send email to.</value>
  </data>
    <data name="plField2.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Email Subject:</value>
  </data>
 <data name="plField2.Help" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Enter the subject for the email you are sending.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="plField3.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Email Message:</value>
  </data>
  <data name="plField3.Help" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Enter the Message for the email you are sending.</value>
  </data>  
</root>
```

View.ascx.cs

## region Copyright

```
// 
// Copyright (c) 2014
// by Scott
// 

#endregion

#region Using Statements

using System;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;

#endregion

namespace Scott.SendEmail
{
    public partial class View : PortalModuleBase
    {       
      #region Event Handlers 
            protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
         base.OnInit(e);
          cmdSave.Click += cmdSave_Click;
        }       
           protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
            ModuleController controller = new ModuleController();
             controller.UpdateModuleSetting(ModuleId, "SendTo", txtField.Text);
             controller.UpdateModuleSetting(ModuleId, "Subject", txtField2.Text);
             controller.UpdateModuleSetting(ModuleId, "Message", txtField3.Text);
              DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMail( "Admin@MarltonLakes.com", 
              txtField.Text, String.Empty,txtField2.Text,
              txtField3.Text, String.Empty,  "html" , String.Empty, 
              String.Empty,String.Empty, String.Empty);  
               Response.Redirect("http://www.MarltonLakes.com");
           }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the place your sending the email to accept HTML email? Or perhaps  its marking the email as potentially dangerous and blocking html content?

Comment: I tried an aol, and gmail address.... both do it

Comment: Are you having trouble editing your question?

Comment: nope there was a few things that got deleted when it was edited by someone else

Comment: OK - there were a lot of rollbacks which were causing the system to signal to us, so I thought I'd check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the text editor control (`txtField3`), you've set `HtmlEncode` to `true`.  Set it to `false` if you don't want the HTML to be encoded.  Because you've set it to true, the editor's `Text` property is giving you `&lt;p&gt;` instead of `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you are setting the content type to `String.Empty`, try the following:

```
    DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMail( "Admin@MarltonLakes.com", 
                  txtField.Text, String.Empty,txtField2.Text,
                  txtField3.Text, String.Empty,  "html" , DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.MailFormat.Text, 
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,String.Empty, String.Empty);  
                   Response.Redirect("http://www.MarltonLakes.com");
```

As per DotNetNuke documentation.

http://www.dotnetnukeru.com/dnndocs/api/html/M_DotNetNuke_Services_Mail_Mail_SendMail_5.htm

Comment: Tried that and I get the following error:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details system.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source Error:
[No relevant source lines]
Source File: App_Web_uqmysdq1.2.cs    Line: 0
Stack Trace:[NullReferenceException:

Comment: @user3223048 I updated my answer, try that please. Also you can remove the error from your comment. Takes too much space and its not entirely readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this behaviour results from the texteditor control.
It uses to add some html content to the text you've entered like paragraph separators. It seems to me that you can configure it to add <p> or <div> in order to separate the different paragraphs.
So, I sugest you to verify if the "txtField3.Text" doesn't correspond to an encoded html content which you have to decode before using. i.e.: <p> encoded correspond to &lt;p&gt; which isn't understood by the clients email as a paragraph.